# write a list as it is in a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a list `l1=['hi','hello',23,1.23]`.

I want to write the text `['hi','hello',23,1.23]` inside a text file, ie, the value of list as it is.

Simple

```
with open('f1.txt','w') as f:
     f.write(l1)
```

doesn't work, so I tried this

```
f=open('f1.txt','w')
l1=map(lambda x:x+',', l1)
f.writelines(l1)
f.close()
```

But this doesn't work either. It says

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

.

How to accomplish this when list contains numbers, alphabets and float?

Comment: You have list `l1=['hi','hello',23,1.23]` and you want to write the text `['hi','hello','welcome']`, but how are these two related?

Comment: However if you would have done `f.write(str(l1))`, it should have worked in the first code-snippet you shared

Comment: Not a dupe because the answers mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python) does not work when the list contains string, numbers float simultaneously.

Comment: some of the answers are for numeric elements too. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/899254/2063361), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6791534/2063361) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107439/2063361)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just:

```
with open('f1.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(l1))
```

Comment: @pstatix why downvote though? Its not like this wont work or anything.

Comment: @RoadRunner I upvoted to remove. I misread the listing of elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can't write the list directly into the file, But first you have to convert your list into the string and then save the string in to the file. 
I have answered the same question back. you can check it here.

[How write a list of list to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845258/how-write-a-list-of-list-to-file/47845356#47845356)

Answer (score -1):

Use the list's `__str__()` method.

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(l1.__str__())
```

The `__str__()` method for any object returns the string that `print` takes; in your case, your formatted list.

Comment: why not just `str(l1)`? `.__str__(..)` is a magic function and it is not a good practice to show magic everywhere (specially when it is not required) :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri oh, I was under the impression from >"I want to write the text ['hi','hello','welcome'] inside a text file" that OP wanted the string's representation

Comment: Yes, the string representation is wanted. But you get that with `str(l1)`.